# psychopy mouse tracking returns true regardless of mouse click

Tags: python, psychopy

I am trying psychopy's mouse tracking feature. For starters, I just want to record if a mouse click occurs or not. Even if I don't click the mouse, it's printing "got pressed". I am using v1.84.2.

```
from psychopy import core, visual, gui, data, misc, event, sound
import time, random, math, os
import numpy as np
import copy
from pygame import mouse, locals, display

screenSize =[1280, 800]
win = visual.Window(size = screenSize, fullscr = True, allowGUI=False, monitor='testMonitor', units='deg')

mouse = event.Mouse(visible=True, newPos=[0,0])

mouse.clickReset()

if mouse.getPressed():
    print ("got pressed")
```

Comment: To record a mouse click, use `if any(mouse.getPressed())` which will register left, right, and scroll click.

Answer (score 1):

`mouse.getPressed()` returns a tuple of 3 elements representing what mouse button was pressed, so `(1, 0, 0)` would indicate the left button is being pressed s your code should look like this:

```
from psychopy import core, visual, gui, data, misc, event, sound
import time, random, math, os
import numpy as np
import copy
from pygame import mouse, locals, display

screenSize =[1280, 800]
win = visual.Window(size = screenSize, fullscr = True, allowGUI=False, monitor='testMonitor', units='deg')

mouse = event.Mouse(visible=True, newPos=[0,0])

mouse.clickReset()

if mouse.getPressed()[0]:
    print ("got pressed")
```